# How to get SonarLint issue stats in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I ran the SonarLint plugin for IntelliJ on all files using the "Analyze all project files" option.

Now, I see the total number of issues and the total number of files. But, the issues are not categorized. So, I don't know how many are Blockers, Critical, Highs, etc.

I read up about SonarLint IntelliJ plugin features [here](https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/), but can't find this information.

The plugin shows results as: [Found 100 issues in 45 files]. How can I see which issue category these 100 issues belong to.